# "An NFT" vs "a NFT"

Tags: articles

I noticed a video titled something like "What is an NFT?" and immediately thought the title is wrong and it should be "what is a NFT?" But after trying to pronounce it with "a" I understand (I think) why people say and write "an NFT". Also did some searching and found both "an NFT" and "a NFT" are used for videos and articles.

Is the easy pronunciation what makes people use "an NFT" or there is some rule for why "an" is used?

Comment: It depends on how you **pronounce** NFT. NFT is generally pronounced as 'en-ef-tee', in which case, it starts with a vowel sound. When an indefinite article is followed by a vowel sound, it should be "an". But if it is pronounced as "non-fungible token", then it should be "a". Spelling has nothing to do with this rule; it depends entirely on the pronunciation. Personally, I would use "an NFT" because most people would pronounce it as an acronym "en-ef-tee".